# unable to get error from SeeJson unit test

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I have a test that checks a api for a json response

```
   public function test_search_get_place_details()
    {
           $this->post('/api/searchVenue', ['placeId' => 'ChIJXZE0JMLeekgR2meph0M9Jm41221212112']);
             $this->SeeJson([
                 'Town' => 'Birkenhead',
             ]);
    }
```

This test works and asserts correctly, but when it fails all I get is

```
Time: 1.42 seconds, Memory: 27.00MB

There was 1 error:

1) SearchTest::test_search_get_place_details
ErrorException: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

/home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Arr.php:494
/home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php:232
/home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php:257
/home/ubuntu/workspace/tests/SearchTest.php:41
```

I assume that this is because the response is a typical laravel error and not json. But I need to know what that error is as it is happening on my CI box, but not locally.

is there anyway to get it to output what ever the response contains on failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can usually get this error due to wrong formatting in your JSON response.
Keep in mind your test is awaiting a valid JSON response, so in that case that's what you need to fix.

1. Can you upload some of your controller code? As that's from where the JSON is coming.
2. Check your framework logs under storage/logs/framework *(if the file is huge, I recommend deleting it and run the request again, you'll get the error logged first)*

Comment: perfect,  I was being lazy and not turning the exception response in to a json array. done that now and i am getting a valid error. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I always find it annoying when a testing framework fails to provide any decent indication as to *what* it saw when it didn't see what I told it to expect. Aside from wrapping a try...catch...report...rethrow around the assertion, I know of no decent way to get the `MakesHttpRequests` trait to spit out what it saw only when the test fails.

However, to debug it, you might go ahead and do that, and use `$this->response` to see what was in the response.

Comment: I added a `->seeStatusCode(200)` before I used `->seeJson()`, which then told me the error: "Failed asserting that 401 matches expected 200."